# Python3.0: tokenize & BytesIO

Tags: python, io, tokenize, bytesio

When attempting to `tokenize` a string in python3.0, why do I get a leading `'utf-8'` before the tokens start?

From the [python3 docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/tokenize.html), `tokenize` should now be used as follows:

```
g = tokenize(BytesIO(s.encode('utf-8')).readline)
```

However, when attempting this at the terminal, the following happens:

```
>>> from tokenize import tokenize
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> g = tokenize(BytesIO('foo'.encode()).readline)
>>> next(g)
(57, 'utf-8', (0, 0), (0, 0), '')
>>> next(g)
(1, 'foo', (1, 0), (1, 3), 'foo')
>>> next(g)
(0, '', (2, 0), (2, 0), '')
>>> next(g)
```

What's with the `utf-8` token that precedes the others?  Is this supposed to happen?  If so, then should I just always skip the first token?

### [edit]

I have found that token type 57 is [tokenize.ENCODING](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.ENCODING), which can easily be filtered out of the token stream if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the coding cookie of the source. You can specify one explicitly:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
do_it()
```

Otherwise Python assumes the default encoding, utf-8 in Python 3.